# CPU bound process?

Tags: central-processing-unit, optimization, cpu-usage

I have a postgresql server process running on my windows computer. When running a query I can see in the process manager that it is using 49% of CPU capacity on my dual core processor and it is also reading about 5 mb/s. My question is if it is possible to conclude that the process is CPU bound? To me it is not obvious that it does not take CPU to read from the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it probably hogs single core of your cpu... so yes - that would suggest it is CPU bound indeed.